# How can I ask hive to provide more detailed error?

Tags: hive

When I run `hive`, it shows the following error

```
[hadoop@a74f90aecdad tmp]$ hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:5099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

What does it mean? Is it possible to show more details?

Comment: `com.google.common.` suggests that you have a version mismatch with either "guava" or "protobuf" JAR. Possibly an older JAR got first in the CLASSPATH, with an older version where class `Preconditions` has no method `checkArgument(String,Object)`.

Comment: _Edit >_ Hive has no control on that thing, it is a low-level error inside the JVM dynamic linker -- and the JVM cannot possibly give you more "detail" than that. It simply states that it has found a class `com.google.common.base.Preconditions` in a JAR present in its CLASSPATH _(assuming Hive does not use a custom ClassLoader that overrides the CLASSPATH)_ but that class does not have the exact method that it had at compile time.

Comment: Try to understand how the CLASSPATH is auto-generated for the legacy `hive` fat client -- e.g.  follow the chain of shell scripts calling shell scripts calling shell scripts, until you find the actual command `java -cp <CLASSPATH> etc etc`

Answer (score 25):

This error pops, when a program is compiled using one version of Jar and executed on other (typically old) version of the same Jar.
In this Scenario, mostly there might be a conflict in the guava Jar file version between Hadoop and Hive.

**step 1**: Go to the **HADOOP_INSTALLATION_DIR/share/hadoop/common/lib** and check the guava.jar version

**step 2**: Now go to **HIVE_INSTALLATION_DIR/lib** and compare the guava file version of hive with hadoop. If they are not same, delete the older version among them and copy the newer version in both.

Comment: The correct path for library in hadoop installation directory is 
HADOOP_INSTALLATION_DIR/share/hadoop/common/lib

Comment: @ShubhashishMishra Yeah, Thanks for correcting me. I will edit it.

Comment: I'm using hadoop 3.2.1(with guava-27.0-jre.jar listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar) and hive 3.1.2 (with guava-19.0.jar), I replace guava-19.0.jar with guava-27.0-jre.jar, but it's still not working,  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x8
 at [row,col,system-id]: [3215,96,"file:/usr/src/hive/conf/hive-site.xml"]

Comment: @EdyeChan I had almost the same versions as you 
- hadoop 3.2.1(with guava-27.0-jre.jar)
- hive 2.3.6(with guava-14.0.1.jar)
I copied guava-27.0-jre.jar from HADOOP_INSTALLATION_DIR/share/hadoop/common/lib to HIVE_INSTALLATION_DIR/lib and it SOLVED THE PROBLEM.

Comment: I have changed hive source code pom.xml with guava version what hadoop is using and rebuilt the same. it worked for me. <guava.version>27.0-jre</guava.version>

Answer (score 14):

Summarizing my answer from a similar question on Super User: https://superuser.com/a/1501841/115371

Hadoop core updated its Guava version in [HADOOP-15960](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15960), which went out in Hadoop 3.0.4, 3.1.3, and 3.2.1.

Hive 3.1.2 ships its own incompatible version of Guava, not only in `lib/guava-*.jar`, but also `hive-exec-*.jar`, a "fat JAR" that repackages several external libraries. The Hive services/CLI don't run without `hive-exec-*.jar`, which means that we can't just delete `guava-*.jar` to get around the compatibility problem.

At the moment, the only options are either:

- Build Hive from the latest source, which should include [HIVE-22126](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22126) to work around the `hive-exec-*.jar` problem, or
- Use Hadoop 3.0.3, 3.2.0, or 3.1.2, the last releases before HADOOP-15960. But note that the Guava JAR shipped with in these Hadoop versions has a **known vulnerability**: [CVE-2018-10237](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-10237).

Comment: Actually, the patch of HIVE-22126 is incorrect. Need to be fixed more.

Comment: Answer is very well written with details like CVE number etc. But it worked by copying newer jar in hive lib dir.